# Fragment state after Custom Dialog Dismiss

Tags: android

I am facing problem regarding **Fragment**. I have a **listview** in custom dialog, on **listview.setOnItemClickListener**, I want to dismiss dialog .I have to do some thing after dismissal of dialog.so what is the state of fragment after dismissal of dialog, or any Listener at dismissal of Dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
//                do sth
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

As show in figure if the view is destroyed then it will again call oncreateview
else you need to write the code in onResume Method

[image: fragment]

Comment: when dialog on a fragment appears then fragment destroyed?are you sure?

Comment: can you share your custom dailog code.

Comment: Because on item click you dismiss the dialog in that code only write whatever you want to call [onItemClick]